# Unable to access Activity Component from Fragment Component in Dagger(Android)

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I am trying to create dependent components for `Activity` and `Fragment`. Here's my **Activity Component**:

```
@Component(modules = [ActivityModule::class],
        dependencies = [AppComponent::class])

interface ActivityComponent{
    fun inject(activity: Activity)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        fun appComponent(component: AppComponent): Builder
        fun activityModule(activityModule: ActivityModule): Builder
        fun build(): ActivityComponent
    }
}

@Module
class ActivityModule(private val activity: Activity) {
    @Provides
    fun provideActivity() = activity
}
```

**Fragment Component:**

```
@Component(modules = [FragmentModule::class],
        dependencies = [ActivityComponent::class])

interface FragmentComponent{
    fun inject(fragment: Fragment)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        fun activityComponent(activityComponent: ActivityComponent): Builder
        fun fragmentModule(fragmentModule: fragmentModule): Builder
        fun build(): FragmentComponent
    }
}

@Module
class FragmentModule(private val fragment: Fragment) {
    @Provides
    fun provideFragment() = fragment
}
```

I am getting a compile error in places where I am trying to access activity.

> Activity cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

It's my understanding that since `Activity` has already been injected in the `ActivityComponent`, and `Fragment` is simply adding itself to the `ActivityComponent`, it should get all the dependencies provided by `ActivityComponent` and `AppComponent`'s modules. I see this happening in `ActivityComponent`, where I get dependencies from `AppComponent` automatically.

**Update**:
If I add the following code to the `FragmentModule`, I am able to get the code compiled:

```
@Provides
fun provideActivity() = fragment.context as Activity
```

But this is not making sense to me, as I was hoping to get the pre-injected `Activity` from `ActivityComponent`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that parent components should always declare the dependencies they want to expose. Otherwise dependent components cannot access them just by declaring them as dependents. Note that transitive dependencies don't work either. So `AppComponent` has to declare a dependency for `ActivityComponent` to use it - but `ActivityComponent` has to re-declare the same dependency if `FragmentComponent` needs it.

```
interface ActivityComponent{
    fun inject(activity: Activity)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        fun appComponent(component: AppComponent): Builder
        fun activityModule(activityModule: ActivityModule): Builder
        fun build(): ActivityComponent
    }
    var activity: Activity
}
```